# how to plan google cloud storage bucket creation when working with users

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to figure out if anyone can offer advice around bucket creation for an app that will have users with an album of photos.  I was initially thinking of creating a single bucket and then prefixing the filename by user id, since google cloud storage doesn't recognize subdirectories, like so: `/bucket-name/user-id1/file.png`

Alternatively, I was considering creating a bucket and naming it by user id like so: `/user-id1-which-is-also-bucket-name/file.png`

I was wondering what I should consider in terms of cost and organization when setting up my google cloud storage. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in term of cost. In term of organization, it's different:

- For the deletion, it's simpler to delete a bucket and not a folder in the unique bucket.
- For performances, sharding is better is you have separate bucket (you have less chance to create an hotspot)
- At billing perspective, you can add labels on the buckets, and get them in the billing exported to BigQuery. You can know the cost of the bucket per user, and maybe do a rebill to them
- The biggest advantage of 1 bucket per user model is the security. You can grant a user (if the users have direct access to the bucket and don't use a backend service to access it) on a bucket, without the use of legacy (and almost deprecated) ACL on object. In addition, if you use ACL, you can't set ACL per folder, ACL are per object. So, everytime that you add an object in the unique bucket, you have to set the ACL on it. It's harder to achieve.

IMO, 1 bucket per user is the best model.